# Microsoft Access 2013 Long Text limiting to 255

Tags: ms-access, ms-office

I have a database that has a field of type long text. It only allows 255 characters and if I add more then it truncates. Tried creating a new table and importing and same issue. Any ideas?

[image: Field Type]

[image: Character Count]

[image: Showing the 255 text max and cant add more]

[image: Data Types Available]

Comment: memo was not an option for a data type.

Comment: `In the design view in the field  properties for the text format for long text, simply select "Rich Text".  All of the text then appears.  It seem that as long as "Plain Text" is selected, then it is limited to 255 characters.  When "Rich Text" is selected, that limit disappeared.` http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-access/long-text-limit-254/7b927011-769f-416d-b0f7-352770270808?db=5&page=2

Comment: That was it "Rich Text". Go figure.... Thanks so much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default the `Long Text` (which was called `Memo` before Office 2013) is set to `Plain Text` which effectively limits the field to 255 (making it not much better than `Short Text`).

You have to go to the design view and change your field to `Rich Text`.

(taken from http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-access/long-text-limit-254/7b927011-769f-416d-b0f7-352770270808?db=5&page=2)

Answer (score 3):

Useful answer. Except if the field is full of HTML tags (which one wants to keep as tags). If one makes the field 'Rich Text' it interprets the contents and one loses the tags. A less than ideal condition.

Answer (score 2):

Check the Format property of your long text field in both the database and any forms for the `@` character.

I removed the format character of `@` and everything appeared. All data over 255 characters was correctly saved in the database but subsequent views of the data only displayed the first 255 characters.

I don't like using Rich Text because it easily causes problems if you try and export the data to Excel or other formats because of the additional formatting characters in Rich Text format.

Answer (score 1):

When you are in the export window, click advanced. It shows a grid of field information.
If you put your mouse over the 'Field name' heading and then move it right the cursor turns to a line with 2 arrows, move farther to the right and it turns to 2 lines with a space and 2 arrows. Click and drag right and you by magic get the skip field, go back to field name heading , do the same again and you magic the indexed, repeat and magic the width then the start and next time the data type. Ah the data type says it will be exported as a short text field, change it to long text and that is what it exports.

Answer (score 1):

I found my solution was to set the query's Subdatasheet name to [Auto] (although after re-opening the query this field appears blank) the query now exports the long text in full. I hope this helps.